# Selenium capture IE and Edge console log

Tags: selenium, webdriver, protractor

I'm able to use:

`let browserLog = await browser.manage().logs().get('browser');
 console.log(util.inspect(browserLog))`

in chrome but, does not work for IE and Edge browsers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2602) article, it looks like `IE` does not support this in any fashion.  It follows that `Edge` would not either.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. The only browser and driver that currently provides the console log is Chrome w/ Chromedriver. It may be added to the W3C Webdriver spec at a later date, follow this issue https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/406

Comment: I bit bizarre, but Edge(Chromium) v87.X appears to implement a default that captures console.warn(),console.error() , but the level is not settable, so console.log() and downwards never gets captured.